# Android AccessibilityNodeInfo performAction ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS

Tags: android, focus, accessibility

I'm developing an accessibility service with similar features to touch to explore.

I can focus menu and home screen icons with

```
public void updateViewNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfo source) {
    source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_FOCUS);
```

The problem is when i reach a listview (for example the settings menu), where the children don't have the tag focusable, they only have the

```
ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS
```

If i use ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS instead of ACTION_FOCUS it simply doesn't focus anything returning always false and i have no idea why.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessibility focus is only supported when Explore by Touch is enabled. See the implementation details at [View.java#6601](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/view/View.java/#6601). There is no workaround, but the net result is simply that you can't control the yellow focus highlight. You can still perform other accessibility actions including ACTION_CLICK.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that was the case. I ended up turning on the Explore by Touch and controling the focus via my service.